# How to redirect wp-admin/index.php to a custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types, redirect, dashboard

I want to redirect my index.php on the admin side to a custom post type.
When I go to mysite.com/wp-admin, it must show a custom post type and not the dashboard.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [wp_redirect](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) to do this.

```
function dashboard_redirect() {
    wp_redirect( admin_url( 'edit.php?post_type=customposttype' ) );
}
add_action('load-index.php', 'dashboard_redirect');
```